# Graphics Card: Overclocking And Operational Life Span

Tags: graphics-card, overclocking, lifespan

I just had to replace my old graphics card because it stopped working after 4,5 years.

My new graphics card is overclocked by default (OC version). Does this mean that its operational life span will be shorter than if it wasn't?

If so, can I disable this overclocking manually to extend its life span?

Comment: There is a simple rule in electronics, heat kills, if the GPU is kept within the temperature specifications of the manfacture it being overclocked will have zero effect on its expected lifespan.  Your GPU was designed to run faster, thus, its thermal requirements were taken into account.

Comment: Thank you. Can you write this as an answer? Than I can officially mark it as such. (PS: Why do I get a "-1" for the question, is it that stupid to not know that?)

Comment: @Cyman Because someone (not me) downvoted your question.

Comment: I don't find your question very well researched to be honest.  I am providing a reason for my vote, because I want to share it, I normally wouldn't share the reason.

Comment: The expected life span of any device is basically it's warranty period.  if the card lasts as long as the warranty, then it's lasting as long as the manufacturer expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you keep it cool, it will be fine. (Same goes for a non-OCed version)

And yes, you can underclock it if you wish.

You can use [EVGA Precision X16](http://www.evga.com/precision/), or [MSI Afterburner](https://gaming.msi.com/features/afterburner) to monitor the temps.

Comment: Thanks.

OK, and how do I (know if I) keep it cool? I didn't plan on doing anything special than plug it in and use it.
If there is no difference to a non-OCed version, there is really no point in underclocking it, is it?

Comment: @Cyman - See updated answer.